# How to prevent access to USB (non storage) device for specific program in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, usb

I need to prevent access to one USB device in Windows Server 2008 so that certain application doesn't see it at all. The application runs as Windows service which can be started with specified user privileges. So hiding the USB device from user would probably do the trick.

NB! This is not USB drive/storage so the usual GPO editing doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We use this tool in our facility.This tool will change the registry settings and makes usb disable.

http://www.freewarefiles.com/USB-Flash-Block-Unblock_program_66453.html

Comment: I don't think You read my post. This app if for USB storage which doesn't help at all.

Comment: Ok plug that specific USB device in server,there are some driver files responsible for that device which can be view using device manager,  browse that 2 or 3 files give that files privilege everyone block full control, whenever you plug that device  the drivers responsible for that files can't work properly because of access rights. Hope this will help.